# Why my Express router is not working with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, routes

I'm trying to create a simple app with NodeJS and TypeScript
Everything is working good except the Express routing. When I try to do a get request is not working, not printing or sending anything.

Heres is my main code

```
"use strict"

import bodyParser from "body-parser"
import express from "express"
import http from "http"
import io from "socket.io"
import cors from "cors"

import { Server as Main } from './interfaces/'

import { Routes } from "./lib/"
const server  = new http.Server(express())
    let  host    = `localhost`

const main: Main = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  app:   express(),
  server, host,
  socket: io(server, {origins:`${host}`})
}


class Server {

  constructor(private main: Main) {
  }

  appConfig() {
    this.main.app.use(cors())
      //.all('*', apikey)
      .use(bodyParser.json())
      .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
  }

  includeRoutes() {
    const routes = new Routes(this.main.app,this.main.socket)
    routes.routesConfig()

  }

  appExecute()  {
    this.appConfig()
    this.includeRoutes()
    const onListening = () => console.log(`Successful at port: ${this.main.port}`)
    this.main.server.listen(this.main.port, onListening)
  }
}
const app = new Server(main)

app.appExecute()
```

here is the routing file

```
'use strict'

import { Request, Response } from "express"

import { Server as Main } from './../interfaces/'

export default class Routes {
  constructor(private app: Main["app"], private socket: Main["socket"])  {}

  appRoutes() {
    console.log(this.app) //<-- this gives me data
    console.log(this.app.get()) //<-- this also gives me data
    this.app.get('/', (req:Request, res:Response)  =>  {
      console.log("test") // not printing
      res.send("test") // not sending
    })
  }

  routesConfig()  {
    this.appRoutes()
  }

}
```

```
import Routes from './routes'

export {
  Routes
}
```

and well, my interface file

```
import { Application } from "express"

export default interface Server {
  port: number|string,
  host: string,
  app:  Application,
  server: any
  socket: any
}
```

If I print app in routing file it gives me all info from express, also the get method but when I enter http://localhost:3000/ is not working, just say `Cannot GET` and doesn't print the console.logs

Comment: In your routing file, what is `nap = express()`?

Comment: Can you remove the `connsole.log(this.app.get())` ?

Comment: I think you haven't instantiated your `app` in Routes constructor. You should create a new instance of express and then call its APIs.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala, sorry I already deleted that. I used to check if the way I was sending the express() to routing file was good.

Comment: @JonasWilms, did it but nothing change. Was a mistake the "nn".

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I already tried to initialise a new instance of express in my route file and nothing. That was the nap = express() line before, also tried inside constructor

Comment: Can you try to make `routesConfig` an arrow function. I think issue is with binding of this.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala that's not the problem cuz I can access to ```routesConfig``` and ```log``` from there. Actually I cannot declare an arrow function inside a ```Class```

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I found the solution, bro. It was something really stupid and still don't know why that change makes it work if it's the same. Thanks for help and your time. You can check solution bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I still don't understand why but I had to change a couple of variables as shown below

```
const app     = express(),
      server  = new http.Server(app),
      host    = `localhost`

const main: Main = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  app, server, host,
  socket: io(server, {origins:`${host}`})
}
```

as you see, I only declared `express()` in `app` variable and then in server I placed app inside `http.Server()`.
I don't really understand why it didn't work before if at least it was the same...
If anyone have the answer, please let me know